# How do I calculate in the background1 DoWork event so the ReportProgress(percentage) will get to 100% and the progressBar1 will get to the end?

Tags: c#

Thats what I did in the DoWork event and in the `ProgressChanged` event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    double total = streamlength;
    int counter = 0;
    int percentage = 0;
    BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    int i = 0;

    for (double x = 0; x < streamlength; x += dt)
    {
        streamDouble[0] = x;
        SaveFramesFromVideo(strVideoFile, streamDouble, sf + i.ToString("D6") + ".bmp");
        i++;
        counter += 1;
        percentage = counter * 100 / (int)total;
        bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

I see the progressBar1 progress with the green color from left to right but in the middle im getting exception in the `ProgressChanged` event:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value of '133' is not valid for 'Value'.
>   'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter name:
>   Value

The error is on the line: `progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;` in the `progressChanged` event.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ExtractFrames.Properties;
using ExtractFrames;
using JockerSoft.Media;
using JockerSoft;
using Interop.qedit;
using Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace ExtractFrames
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double dt;
        FolderBrowserDialog fb;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1;
        private bool _connect = false;
        private bool _rightButton;
        List<LinePoint> _points = null;
        private float _circleWidth = 10;
        DirectoryInfo dir1;
        FileInfo[] fi;
        double streamlength;
        MediaDet mdd;
        double x;
        string sf;
        double[] streamDouble ;
        string strVideoFile;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            mdd = new MediaDet();
            streamDouble = new double[1];
            sf = @"d:\Frames\";
            dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(sf);
            fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.bmp");
            if (fi.Length == 0)
            {
                trackBar1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                trackBar1.Maximum = fi.Length - 1;
                trackBar1.Value = 0;//fi.Length - 1;
                Bitmap newImage;
                newImage = new Bitmap(fi[0].FullName);
                pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
            }
        }

        private  void getFrameRate()
        {
            // Get framerate
            MediaDet md = new MediaDet();
            md.Filename = strVideoFile;
            //md.CurrentStream = 0;                     // choose the video stream
            x = md.FrameRate;
            double i = md.StreamLength;

        }

        public static void SaveFramesFromVideo(string videoFile, double[] positions, string outputBitmapFiles)
        {
            if (videoFile == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("videoFile");

            double streamLength;

            IMediaDet mediaDet = null;
            try
            {
                _AMMediaType mediaType;
                if (openVideoStream(videoFile, out mediaDet, out mediaType))
                {
                    streamLength = mediaDet.StreamLength;
                    Size target = getVideoSize(mediaType);
                    int iteration = 0;
                    foreach (double position in positions)
                    {
                        iteration++;
                        string outputBitmapFile = string.Format(outputBitmapFiles, iteration);                        
                        mediaDet.WriteBitmapBits(position, target.Width, target.Height, outputBitmapFile);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
                throw new InvalidVideoFileException();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mediaDet != null)
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDet);
            }

            return;

        }


        private static Size getVideoSize(_AMMediaType mediaType)
        {
            WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER videoInfo = (WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.pbFormat, typeof(WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER));

            return new Size(videoInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, videoInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);
        }

        private static Size scaleToFit(Size target, Size original)
        {
            if (target.Height * original.Width > target.Width * original.Height)
                target.Height = target.Width * original.Height / original.Width;
            else
                target.Width = target.Height * original.Width / original.Height;

            return target;
        }
        private static Size scaleToFitSmart(Size target, Size original)
        {
            target = scaleToFit(target, original);

            if (target.Width > original.Width || target.Height > original.Height)
                return original;

            return target;
        }

        private static bool openVideoStream(string videoFile, out IMediaDet mediaDet, out _AMMediaType aMMediaType)
        {
            mediaDet = new MediaDet();

            //loads file
            mediaDet.Filename = videoFile;

            //gets # of streams
            int streamsNumber = mediaDet.OutputStreams;

            //finds a video stream
            for (int i = 0; i < streamsNumber; i++)
            {
                mediaDet.CurrentStream = i;
                _AMMediaType mediaType = mediaDet.StreamMediaType;

                if (mediaType.majortype == JockerSoft.Media.MayorTypes.MEDIATYPE_Video)
                {
                    //video stream found
                    aMMediaType = mediaType;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            //no video stream found
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDet);
            mediaDet = null;
            aMMediaType = new _AMMediaType();
            return false;
        }


        private bool LoadPictureAt(int nIndex, object c)
        {

            bool bRet = false;

            if (nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < fi.Length)
            {
                if (c.Equals(trackBar1))

                    pictureBox1.Load(fi[nIndex].FullName);
                bRet = true;

            }

            return bRet;
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPictureAt(trackBar1.Value, sender);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_points != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                using (SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _points.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Point pt = _points[i].Point;
                            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new RectangleF(pt.X - _circleWidth / 2F, pt.Y - _circleWidth / 2F, _circleWidth, _circleWidth));

                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                if (_points[i].Connected)
                                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, _points[i - 1].Point, _points[i].Point);
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( Exception err)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text = err.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (_points == null)
                    _points = new List<LinePoint>();
                _points.Add(new LinePoint() { Point = new Point(e.X, e.Y), Connected = _connect });
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                _connect = !_connect;
                _rightButton = true;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _points.Clear();
            if (_rightButton && _points != null)
                _points.Clear();

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _rightButton = false;
        }

        public class LinePoint
        {
            public Point Point { get; set; }
            public bool Connected { get; set; }
        }

        private void loadVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a video file";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = null;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Video Files|*.wmv;*.3gp;*.avi";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            DialogResult result1 = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string file1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            if (result1 == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                strVideoFile = file1;
                mdd.Filename = strVideoFile;
                streamlength = mdd.StreamLength;
                dt = (double)1 / mdd.FrameRate;//(double)20; //mdd.FrameRate;
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            if (result1 == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                if (file1 == "")
                {
                }
            }
        }

        private void changeExtractedFramesDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fb.Description = "Directory To Extract Frames";
            DialogResult result = fb.ShowDialog();
            string file1 = fb.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            double total = streamlength;
            int counter = 0;
            int percentage = 0;
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            int i = 1;
            for (double x = 0; x < total; x += dt)
            {
                streamDouble[0] = x;
                SaveFramesFromVideo(strVideoFile, streamDouble, sf + i.ToString("D6") + ".bmp");
                i++;
                counter += 1;
                //percentage = counter * 100 / (int)total;
                percentage = (int)((x / streamlength) * 100.0); 
                bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);
            }
            bgw.ReportProgress(100);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            progressBar1.Value = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, e.ProgressPercentage)); 
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            fi = dir1.GetFiles("*.bmp");
            if (fi.Length == 0)
            {
                trackBar1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                trackBar1.Enabled = true;
                trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
                trackBar1.Maximum = fi.Length - 1;
                trackBar1.Value = 0;//fi.Length - 1;
                Bitmap newImage;
                newImage = new Bitmap(fi[0].FullName);
                pictureBox1.Image = newImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: percentage should always be between 0 and 100 right? UR passing 133 here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the declaration of the variables `streamlength` and `dt`. The backgroundworker (as its name suggests) *works in the background*. So your program is working in parallel, the UI is reactive and it might be possible that the value of streamlength is changed while backgroundworker is working. In that case the for loop is running to a different end `streamlength` then the calculation of the percentage (you stored `streamlength` in `total` and use that for calculating) A first approach is to change the method `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` in that way:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    double total = streamlength;
    int counter = 0;
    int percentage = 0;
    BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    int i = 0;
    for (double x = 0; x < total; x += dt)
    {
        streamDouble[0] = x;
        SaveFramesFromVideo(strVideoFile, streamDouble, sf + i.ToString("D6") + ".bmp");
        i++;
        counter += 1;
        percentage = counter * 100 / (int)total;
        bgw.ReportProgress(percentage);
    }
}
```

That should work now, but I would highly advise you to rethink the program.

Comment: I just edited the question and put in the complete code you can see it now in the top where im asking.

Comment: @ShakulShakuli: Come on, Pieter and I gave you enough hints so you can find the error. It's useless to post **all** your code. And it's near to spam, if you post empty methods and commented-out code! You will get hints and help from Stack Overflow, but that is not a platform to make a code review!

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following changes. First, change the calculation of the percentage to:

```
percentage = (int)((x / streamlength) * 100.0);
```

This uses `x` instead of a counter. I would make this change because this is what you're actually using to loop.

Next, to ensure you don't get problems because of rounding errors, you could change assigning the value to the progress bar to:

```
progressBar1.Value = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, e.ProgressPercentage));
```

This will ensure that the assigned value is always between 0 and 100.

Comment: Pieter i used Fischermaen above solution and then changed the two lines as you suggested and its working but in the end the progressBar1 green color stop just a little bit before the end it dosent get to the end completed. Very liittle ot the end it stop.

Comment: Just add `bgw.ReportProgress(100);` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Pieter i did and just checked now the progressBar1 is getting to 100% the green is getting to the end but in realtime i saw also the directory where its creating the files to and after the progressBar1 is on 100% the program still creating some files. Like there is no a sync between the files creation on the disk and the progressBar1.

Comment: I'm afraid I would not be able to help you with that because solving this depends too much on the rest of your application.